# How to make a function accept a local variable as a parameter

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have defined the following functions

```
def f(x):
    return x*a

def g(x,a):
    return f(x)

g(1,2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Now if I try to evaluate `g(x,a)` for any value of `x` and `a` it states that `a` is not defined. I suspect this is because `a` should be a global variable.

I have heard that using global variables is bad practice so my question is how do I make `g(x,a)` give a result with `a` given as an argument?

Note: The reason I am not giving `a` as an argument to `f(x)` is because it needs to be solved as a differential equation (using scipy) with only the relevant variables as arguments.

Comment: If `f` is using `a` then `a` is definitely relevant to define `f`. What's the mathematical equation you want to solve?

Comment: The actual functions involved are much more complicated, but the gist is `g` is a chi-square and `a` is one of the parameters. `f` is a function that depends on the parameter `a`. The differential equation is something like dx/dt=f(x) with `a` as the parameter. Scipy only solves if the function has arguments that are present in the differential equation. Hence `f` cannot accept `a` as an argument.

Comment: `a` is a parameter that will be varied and the differential equation will be solved for each `a`

Comment: "The reason I am not giving a as an argument to f(x) is because it needs to be solved as a differential equation (using scipy) with only the relevant variables as arguments." - that's why SciPy solvers have an `args` argument to specify additional arguments for the function you pass to the solver.

Comment: For the ones that don't have such an argument, you can use `functools.partial`, or a closure (but beware of late binding if you use a closure).

Comment: Ok yes I think that solves my problem. Thank you. However as a purely academic question is it possible to make `g(x,a)` give a value without passing `a` to `f`? Or do I have to resort to setting `a` as a global variable?

Comment: This question needs a complete MRE, what is provide falls short.

Comment: @itprorh66 I am not familiar with the abbreviation MRE, could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: @itprorh66 I have edited the code to include an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

Since a is a variable within the function g, why not avoid the entire global situation by the following:

```
def f(x):
    # do something to alter x
    return x

def g(x, a):
    return f(x)*a

g(1,2) # returns f(x) *2
```